# Snowflake: join two select statements

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**DISCLAIMER: NEW TO SQL AND SNOWFLAKE**  ... so before you engage in anti-consumer abuse...

Suppose I have two select statements:

```
select foo,bar from baz as b;

select foo,bar,gee,whiz from qaz as q;
```

Suppose the second select statement has a join:

```
select foo, bar, gee, whiz from qaz as q

left join data as d on (d.gee = q.gee)
where d.whiz = q.whiz
and q.foo is not NULL
```

Now, how do I combine these two distinct selects into a left join?

```
select foo,bar from baz as b
left join

( select foo, bar, gee, whiz from qaz as q
  left join data as d on (d.gee = q.gee)
  where d.whiz = q.whiz and q.foo is not NULL
) this

on b.foo = this.foo
where b.bar = this.bar
order by b.foo desc
limit 1
```

The above does not work.  Computing the above locally is out of the question: with only 20,000 rows, pandas nabs more than 20gb of memory.  How does one compute this dataset with Snowflake?

Comment: Can you clarify "does not work" in your statement?  Are you getting unexpected results, or is the statement failing?  Also, the relationship/uniqueness of these 2 tables on the JOIN criteria that you are using would be helpful.  One quick comment, as well, you are using WHERE for your join criteria.  You should be including that relationship in your actual JOIN condition (d.whiz = q.whiz).

Comment: @MikeWalton I got it working, it is just intractible. And "should be" -- is this an aesthetic preference, or a semantic difference?

Comment: "should be" means not ANSI SQL standard (as well as aesthetic preference).  It's an implicit join, which is no longer a standard.  Snowflake will handle it either way, though.

Comment: @MikeWalton so it is semantically equivalent.  I am just checking if this is a tomato-vs-to-mah-to sports bar "did both toes touch the turf and was the ball under control" conversation, or one with actionable content

Comment: "left join data as d on (d.gee = q.gee) where d.whiz = q.whiz" is different from "left join data as d on d.gee = q.gee and d.whiz = q.whiz" and the give different results. The first returns every q with the matching d's based on gee, and then throws away any q and d rows there whiz is not the same, (which means all the left joins are also dropped) and so it really should be written "join data as d on d.gee = q.gee and d.whiz = q.whiz" but now it's a normal JOIN it doesn't matter where the filters are.